# Postfix/Dove copy incoming outgoing emails

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have to copy a mail account's incoming and sent mails to another mail account on the same server as well. How can I do this?

The server is a debian wheezy running dovecot, roundcube and postfix. As I said the email isn't just an alias but an existing mailbox. The copying of the incoming mails can easily done with a sieve file in the user's profile:

01_forward.sieve

```
require ["fileinto"];
fileinto "Inbox";
redirect "user2@mail.com";
```

But as for getting a copy of every sent letters forwarded to user2@mail.com as well. I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: are you using procmail? if not, you could use it to create a filter on all incoming and outgoing mail

Comment: This will be a postfix setting.  Look at the [virtual](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html) and [aliases](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html) functions, you should be able to achieve what you desire.

Answer (score 2):

Postfix should be enough to this scenario. Check the [sender_bcc_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_bcc_maps) and [recipient_bcc_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_bcc_maps)  feature. As documented, two parameters defines an mapping where copies of particular mail account handled by postfix are sent to.

Assuming that your mail account is **user@example.com** and you want to copy it to **external@example.net**.

```
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/special_user
recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/special_user
```

In `/etc/postfix/special_user` add this line

```
user@example.com    external@example.net
```

Don't forget to postmap the map file and run `postfix reload`